# css transiton and css animation cannot be used together

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions

I have scenario where I need to open the music player on clicking a button and close the player on clicking on the close button. I am using the `showPlayer` state variable to show and hide the player as well as for the classes for enter and exit animation.

```
<div className={`${showPlayer ? 'show-player' : 'hide-player'} player-container `}></div>
```

Below is the style I am using

```
.player-container {
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0%;
    width: 23rem;
    background: $graph_box_gradient;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;

    &.show-player {
        animation: slideInRight .5s ease forwards;
    }

    &.hide-player {
        animation: slideOutRight .5s ease forwards;
    }
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
    0% {
        right: -100%;
    }
    100% {
        right: 0%;
    }
}

@keyframes slideOutRight {
    0% {
        right: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        right: -100%;
    }
}
```

The issue That I face here is that when the page is loaded the `showPlayer` value is `false` and the `hide-player` class is attached to the div. As a result the player component is initially shown sliding out of the screen on the page load.

Solution 1:
I Tried a solution as following:

```
&.show-player {
    animation: slideInRight .5s ease forwards;
}

&.hide-player {
    right: -100%;
    transition: 1s ease;
}
```

Use `animation` property for enter animation and use `transition` property for exit animation. But it seems like `transition` property does not work when `animation` is given for the same element.

Solution 2:
Tried another solution:

```
playerRef.current.classList.add('hide-player');
```

Created a ref for the player component and added `hide-player` class on the button click. But here the `showPlayer` state is changed and the component re-renders ad the `hide-player` class is not attached.

Solution 3:

```
.player-container {
    transiton:.5s ease

    &.show-player {
        right: 0%;
    }

    &.hide-player {
        right: -100%;
    }
}
```

This method works. But the component is kind of hovering and movable. I am using `<Draggable>` library for the purpose. So when using transition for `show-player` class, the transition gets applied when the component is moved around. Which I would not prefer.

Seems like I am approaching this the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Editted:**

Since your player is either shown or hidden, you should only need (in your css) to have a default position (class) and another one for your component state (shown or hidden).

Also, your animation is rather simple, so keyframes animation do not seem to be the solution for me.

Your third solution would seem the more appropriate to me.

If `<Draggable>` is using the `transform` property for its animation, and you do not want your `transition` to mess with it, you should specify that you only want your transition to apply for `right` property.

```
<div className={`${showPlayer ? '' : 'hide-player'} player-container `}></div>
```

```
.player-container {
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0%;
    width: 23rem;
    background: $graph_box_gradient;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    transition: right .5s ease; // .5s transition only for right property

    &.hide-player {
        right: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. But this method does not work for me. If I give transition property for the player element, it gets applied when the played is moved around. I have explained that scenario in my question as solution #3. If the player was stationary I could use the transition property.

Comment: The slight difference here, is that the transition property is only applied on the transform property.

I don't know which proprerty `<Draggable>` is using, but the idea would be to add a transition on the properties it is not using.

Comment: I checked the `<Draggable>` uses `transform:translate` to make the element draggable

Comment: Okay, I editted my answer, give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thanks you so much. `transform: translate(0, 0);` this line is also not necessary i think. Works fine without this line. May because of the `<Draggable>` library

Comment: Yep you're right, forgot to remove it when I editted. It's now removed. Glad it helped !